# Creating a bootable DVD

Tags: bootable-media, ghost-image

I made a Windows XP ghost image of about 4.2 GB size. I now want to write this image onto a DVD and make it bootable, so that I can apply the image any time OS is corrupted.

How do I do this?

Comment: I assume by "ghost image" you refer to an image created using Norton Ghost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know there is no easy way to do this with Windows.  If you just want it for system recovery, i'd recommend [gNewSense](http://www.gnewsense.org/); you should be able to do a raw data transfer from a disk image stored on a DVD (though i'm not sure about this, as it's never come up for me).